# Spark does not preserved encoding of **some** unicode chars

Tags: apache-spark, unicode

It seems that the encoding of **some** unicode chars are not preserved when it is serialized by spark.

An example:

```scala
val str ="string with unicodes \u202F and \uD83C"
val range = "[\u202F\uD800-\uDB7F]+"
str.replaceAll(range, "gotcha!") // "string with unicodes gotcha! and gotcha!"
```

but doing the same thing after wrapping this string in a dataset of string

```scala
val ds = Seq(str).toDS()
ds.map(s => s.replaceAll(range, "gotcha!")).first // "string with unicodes gotcha! and ?"
```

Any idea how this can happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U+D83C in isolation is not a valid UTF-16 sequence, it is the first half of a surrogate pair.

The ranges you used seem to suggest that you are at least vaguely aware that D800 through DBFF are reserved; you should probably read up on [the mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U+010000_to_U+10FFFF).

Answer (score 1):

U+D83C is a [high surrogate](http://enwp.org/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Special_code_points). It cannot be encoded on its own.